# Open iFrame in new window with specific size and position

Tags: iframe, window.open, document.write

Newbie question here. I have searched a lot and found different parts of the solution but I cannot work out how to put everything together. I hope you can help me.

I need to add a link to my site which will open a new window with specific size in the bottom right corner of the screen. I found this code doing exactly that:

```
 <a onClick="openWindow(); return false;"http://www.example.com">Ask your question!</a>
      <script>
    var topsss=screen.height-500;
    var left=screen.width-400;
    function openWindow() {
        window.open("http://www.example.com", "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top="+topsss+",left="+left+",width=400,height=500");
    }
</script>
```

Within the new window I don't want to show mysite.com but I need an iFrame showing the content.

I managed to get a new window with the iFrame but the content is not showing in the iFrame:

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=420,height=515");
      myWindow.document.write('<iframe width="400" height="500" src="http://www.example.com" 
    frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    }
   </script>
```

Can you help me to put this all together and make this work?

Thanks for your help!

//Manon

Comment: Would it be better if you would put it into a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to display a form for the user to fill, instead of opening new page for that.

Would it be possible to contain that form/page for all of your pages and have CSS trick to show/hide it? I know it's not what you are asking but the iframes and new pages could just cause you problems, cross-domain-scripting, and overall iframe is controversila (some consider it dead and deprecated by html5). So there might be a more elegant way to do the same with just CSS/JS, you can do more conditions, more controls where it will be placed and what it will do (animations, effects, some interaction with your original page).

https://allyjs.io/tutorials/hiding-elements.html

If you are making a SPA style website then maybe you are not aware of SPA frameworks? There is a lot of JavaScripts frameworks doing these things for you:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application